# Getting always last value when trying to create a radio button using loop in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to create a radio button using a loop

```
<?= $this->Form->create($account) ?>
<?php foreach($gametitles as $gametitle): ?>
        <?= $this->Form->radio(
                  'gametitle_id',
                         [
                           ['value' => $gametitle->id,'text'=>'','hiddenField' => false],
                         ]
             ); 
        ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

I have added `'hiddenField' => false` , but in DOM I'm seeing still hidden field displaying. In output I'm getting always empty value if I select without last radio button.

```
[
'gametitle_id' => '',
]
```

If I use name as an array `gametitle_id[]` I am getting an array

```
'gametitle_id' => [
(int) 0 => '',
(int) 1 => '',
(int) 2 => '4',
(int) 3 => '',
(int) 4 => '',
],
```

How I will get only one value that has selected in radio button ? I have used `'hiddenField' => false`, still why hidden field is displaying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `'hiddenField' => false` in options ! You have to set it with name.

```
echo $this->Form->radio(
    'favorite_color',
    [
        ['value' => 'r', 'text' => 'Red', 'style' => 'color:red;']
    ],
    ['hiddenField' => false]
)
```